# Excel array and collection passing between modules messing up values

Tags: vba, excel, automation, office-automation

This is really stumping me. I put a question up yesterday regarding collections being passed between modules ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744344/excel-vba-workbook-not-adding-to-object-collection)), but it doesn't seem like I am getting anymore explanations on that one, so i am attempting to restate the problem more clearly in a generic way.

I have a module (module1) and a userform (userform1). I create a collection (or array) in userform1 and add worksheet objects to this array. I then pass control to module1, which calls a sub in userform1 called addNewFile, which is supposed to add the newly created workbook to the collection. However, each time module1 calls addNewFile i get one of two scenarios: 1) the collection has been erased and all worksheets that had been added are now gone (for a collection), 2) i get an error saying that i have a type mismatch (for an array). I don't know why this is happening, so here is the code below to illustrate better. Any help would be appreciated, even if it is just to tell me that it is not possible to store worksheet objects in arrays.

UserForm1

```
Dim workBooksCollection as New Collection 'can also define as an array
Private Sub CommandButton1_click()

   Dim mainWorkBook as workbook
   Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
   Dim testwb As Workbook

   workBooksCollection.Add Item:=mainWorkBook, key:="main" 'Adds successfully
   workBooksCollection.Add Item:=testwb, key:="test" 'Adds successfully
   MsgBox "the size of the array is: " & usedWorkBooks.Count 'Prints off as size 2

   Module1.initialize

   'After running initialize, prints off as size 0, meaning collection has been erased
   MsgBox "the size of the array is: " & usedWorkBooks.Count 'Prints off as size 0

End Sub
Public Sub addNewFile(filepath As String, sheetKey As String)
   Dim newWorkBook As Workbook  
   Set newWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

   MsgBox "The name of the workbook is: " & newWorkBook.name  'Prints off name of workbook successfully

   workBooksCollection.Add Item:=newWorkBook, key:=sheetKey
   MsgBox "the size of the array is: " & workBooksCollection.Count 'Prints off as size 1
End Sub
```

Module1

```
Public Sub intialize()
   Dim filepath as string
   'The filepath is set to any path of a workbook 

   'This will print out that the array size is 1
   UserForm1.addNewFile filePath, "secondBook"

End Sub
```

Sorry if i seem to be beating a dead horse here, but I really don't have any idea what is going on here. I am used to the idea of collections and lists being global and not changing when being referenced by another module. Any help on what is going on here would be great.

Comment: Also, this happens for all datatypes, not just workbooks.

Comment: you don't seem to be initializing your `workBooksCollection` collection object (`Set workBooksCollection =New collection`).  Where does that happen?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the New operator before the workBooksCollection. It now reades `Dim workBooksCollection as New Collection`

Comment: How are you showing your form?

Comment: At the moment I am just running it in the Developer environment of Excel. I haven't worked out how I want to show it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to comment, but I can't since I had to redo my account because I got locked out of my original.

If my answer isn't helpful, I will delete in a bit, but what if you replace -

```
Dim workBooksCollection as collection 'can also define as an array
```

from the UserForm module, into Module 1 as:

```
Public workBooksCollection as collection 'can also define as an array
```

Does it help?

Comment: This was the problem all along. I have been beating my head against a wall for two days now! Thank you, that really was simple and I knew it had to be.

Comment: @derigible - I'm kind of surprised by this being the answer to your problem. If your collection variable is defined in the userform but *only accessed via methods also in the userform*, it shouldn't need to be declared as Public.

Comment: @TimWilliams That is what I thought, but I could not get it to work. I am not too familiar with scope in VBA, and I am coming to learn that there are lots of weird rules in VBA not found in other languages. I just know that this answer works. If you have a solution to why the accessor methods aren't working i would love to know.

Comment: What is the "usedWorkbooks" variable referring to in your original code?  I don't see that defined anywhere...  And your sub named "intialize": looks like a typo? After fixing those your code ran fine for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, sorry, i have since edited the code. Initialize is actually intializeProcess, but i just shortened it. Everything here runs fine now.